# Translating in Perl (brief)

Tags: python, arrays, perl, hash

I am having trouble translatin this section to python.
If you guys could help it would be great!
Thanks!

> ```
> @Node_Coords = ($x, $y, $z, $ZYX[$z][$y][$x][0]);
>   push @{ $HoA{$BufferNum} } , @Node_Coords;
> ```

Comment: What does it do? Describe it in words and more people will be able to help you.

Comment: It is a hash and an array, it is to create an array trying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
node_coords = x, y, z, zyx[z][y][x][0]
hoa[buffer_name].extend(node_coords)
```